# How to add timestamp in local time in momentjs

Tags: javascript, node.js, momentjs

I am using `moment.js` and have `date` and `time` in number/timestamp. I want to convert it in my local timestamp i.e, `GMT+5:30`. Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4jd3vtp5/1/) link.

code:-

```
console.log(moment(1489689000000).add(52200000).toDate())

  //output: Fri Mar 17 2017 14:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
 //expected output : Fri Mar 17 2017 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

Comment: moment.js will pull local time anyway, as per the documentation, try moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here some other way to achieve this. As per your `GMT +5.30` timezone So, you just convert hour to milliseconds.

```
console.log(moment(1489689000000).add(52200000+ 19800000).toDate());

 // here 5.5 hours =  19800000 miliseconds
// add  + 19800000 due GMT +5.30
```

Answer (score 1):

### Moment

If you want to use plain `moment` like in your question:

You may try to use `moment.utc()` if you want your date to be parsed as UTC:

```
console.log(moment.utc(1489689000000).add(52200000).local().toDate());
```

or:

```
console.log(moment(moment.utc(1489689000000).add(52200000).local()));
```

but **this may not actually do what you need** - depending on your system config.

### Moment Timezone

If you're serious with time zones then **you should be using `moment-timezone`**:

```
var moment = require('moment-timezone');
var zone = moment.tz.guess();
console.log(moment.utc(1489689000000).add(52200000).tz(zone).format());
```

See:

- http://momentjs.com/timezone/
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment-timezone

Comment: I think your code is also giving   Fri Mar 17 2017 14:30:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

 But expected output is mentioned as  Fri Mar 17 2017 20:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)

Comment: not desire output..! actually the number `52200000` come from front end `bs-datepicker` when i select `20:00' from dropdown

Comment: @user7104874 See my updated answer - the last example and links.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally for your local timezone - moment object will give you the perfect date

```
moment().toDate() // Fri Mar 17 2017 20:18:53 GMT+0530 (IST)
```

but if you want for different timezone's, perfect way is to convert [using moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/)

```
moment().tz(timezone)toDate()
eg. moment().tz('Asia/calcutta').toDate() // Fri Mar 17 2017 20:20:49 GMT+0530 (IST)
```